# Area triangle (possible)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The area of a right triangle is an integer greater than $ 85 $. If the hypotenuse measures $ 20 $, what is the area of this triangle?

It’s just a 3-4-5 right triangle, so the area is $\boxed{96}$.
This is true? If so, how to prove it?

But he said the area is integer, not the sides

Can you use Weitzenbock inequality in this problem?

Comment: You can show that 3-4-5 is the only Pythagorean triple that satisfies your criteria.

Comment: 3-4-5 right triangle is one of the hyphotesis?

Comment: @MatheusNunes yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

The area of the right triangle with hypotenuse $|AB|=20$
can be any real number in a range  $(0,100]$, 
so if the only limiting condition is that it must be an integer greater than $85$,
the answer is that it could be any integer $n$ from $86$ to $100$.

[image]

Comment: But the question is *If the hypotenuse measures 20, what is the area of this triangle?*

Comment: @CroCo: And the answer is: the area could be any integer $n$ from $86$ to $100$.

Answer (score 3):

We need

$$a^2+b^2=20^2\implies a^2=400-b^2$$

which by inspection, taking $a$ and $b$ integers, leads to the unique solution $a=12$ and $b=16$ such that $\frac12 ab\ge 85$ and the area in that case is equal to $96$.

For $a$ and $b$ reals we have

$$\frac12ab=\frac12a\sqrt{400-a^2}=86 \implies a\sqrt{400-a^2}=172 $$$$\implies a=\sqrt{186}\pm\sqrt{14},\quad b=\sqrt{186}\mp\sqrt{14}$$

which is the unique solution for the area equal to $86$.

In a similar way we can obtain integer solutions up to $100$ which is the largest area we can obtain for $a=b=10 \sqrt 2$.

Comment: The area would not be 86?

Comment: We have $16\cdot 6=96$.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be 86?

Comment: He didn't say the sides are integers, just the area

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi Ah ok! Sorry I didn't see that. I try to revise the solution.

Comment: So you assumed the area is 86?

Comment: The first integer greater than 85 is 86 and we can find the solution for a and b reals.

Comment: Anyway check whether or not in the original problem a and b need to be integer too.

Comment: It suffices to prove that  $a\sqrt{400-a^2}=172$ has a real solution and we are done.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but why?

Comment: It can be easily shown that the area can be any integer from $86$ to $100$. I’ve shown how to get the minimum integer area greater than $85$. The max area $100$ is obtained for $a=b=10\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 0):

If the hypotenuse is $20$, the ratio is then $4$ times that of a $3-4-5$ triangle or $12:16:20$. Now the area is $\frac{1}{2} \times 12 \times 16 = 96$ which is indeed greater than $85$.